# numfmt_format() expects parameter 1 to be NumberFormatter, null given

Tags: php, localization, wamp, icu, intl

I recently upgraded my WAMP server and I can't seem to get the Intl extension to work. I've made sure that

- the extension path in both ini files are correct
- the extension is loaded in both inis
- I can see the extension with `php --re intl`
- I can see an example function with `php --rf numfmt_create`
- I have icu dlls files in my php folder (icu 46, php 5.3.8, wamp 2.2)
- I have appended `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8` to the PATH in System variables
- The code is correct - working code before wamp upgrade and php manual example codes fail

I'm trying to use the Number Formatter but it gives me some strange errors. Take this example code from the php manual for example:

```
<?php
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
echo numfmt_format($fmt, 1234567.891234567890000)."\n";
$fmt = numfmt_create( 'it', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
echo numfmt_format($fmt, 1142)."\n";
?>
```

It gives me this:

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: numfmt_format() expects parameter 1 to be NumberFormatter,
>   null given
>
> Filename: controllers/test.php
>
> Line Number: 867
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\application\controllers\test.php Line: 867
>   Function: numfmt_format
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\index.php Line: 260 Function: require_once

---

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: numfmt_format() expects parameter 1 to be NumberFormatter,
>   null given
>
> Filename: controllers/test.php
>
> Line Number: 869
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\application\controllers\test.php Line: 869
>   Function: numfmt_format
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\index.php Line: 260 Function: require_once

I notice that `numfmt_create()` seems to be returning NULL regardless of what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the 64 version of WAMP did not have correct icu dlls - using the 32 version worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you run the `icuinfo.exe` tool from ICU to see if ICU is loading its data properly?